# Using console in VCL applications

Tags: c++builder, vcl

Is there a way for using the console for output in VCL applications? Where does `cout` actually direct the stream in VCL applications?

Comment: @Ron In VCL application no console is appeared when running  `std::cout<<"some_text;` statement. I guess the global object `std::cout` is initialized differently in VCL and Console Applications.

Comment: Indeed there should not be a console app popping up when you have a `std::cout<<"...";` statement somewhere in your code. It writes to stdout but since there is no stdout, nothing is shown. It doesn't mean a console application should pop up.

Comment: @maksim_volodin Why using ancient `cout` and console in VCL? TMemo and AnsiString is  much more comfortable and I think even faster ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it as follows:

```
void TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    out_to_console("Some text\n");
}
void out_to_console(std::string str)
{
    AllocConsole() ;
    AttachConsole(GetCurrentProcessId()) ;
    std::freopen("CON", "w", stdout) ;
    std::cout<<str;
}
```

Two questions still remain for me open:

1. Why I need the escape sequence `\n` to see the text `Some text` on the console?
2. Where does `stdout`point to in VCL applications?

Comment: `std::cout`/`stdout` is typically line-buffered by default, so you need `\n` or an explicit `flush` to see the output. By default, `stdout` (and by extension, `std::cout`) doesn't point anywhere in a VCL GUI app, because a GUI app is not a Console app, that is the whole point. If you want console output, make a Console app, not a GUI app. Or, as you already discovered, make a new Console window and redirect `stdout` to it. But there is very little use for a console window in a GUI app, except maybe for debugging purposes. Otherwise, why are you not simply outputting to your own GUI instead?